# Get the sum of a function in python

Tags: python, function, sum

**My code:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def dice():
    import random
    number = random.randint(1,6)
    print "The dice shows:" + str(number)

[dice() for _ in range(3)]
```

**Example result:**

```
The dice shows:2
The dice shows:4
The dice shows:3
```

If I want to sum all the numbers in the list, how do I do that? (In this case, I would get the sum 9)

Comment: Use `sum()`. (And don't import `random` in the function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you should read a little bit more Python [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions), because you have some doubts even before logic.

Here is what I think you wan to do.

```
import random

def dice():
    return random.randint(1,6)

sum([dice() for i in range(3)])
```

Your function is printing result as string, not returning the result.

Comment: Thanks for the link and answer, my first day for trying out Python. Fun, but hard! :)

Answer (score 0):

For manual suming:

```
import random
def dice():
  return random.randint(1,6)

list = []
for i in range(3):
  list.append(dice())

sum = 0 
for i in list:
   sum +=i
print sum
```

Built in suming:

```
print sum([dic() for _ in range(3))
```